# How to remove cookies in servlets on window close or while application re-run is happening

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, servlets, cookies

As the title said, I want to remove the cookies when I close a window. I know of the methods for cookies like `Cookies.removeCookie(Constants.XXX);` And also of `cookie.setMaxAge(0);`
for removing cookies. But that is done on clicking logout.

I want to remove cookies on window close or when application has stopped running. Because whenever, I am debugging the application, whenever I rerun the application, I see the cookie is still there even though I am not logged in, and the session has not started for the user. So there is a conflict, where the cookie is already set even though, the user has still not logged in !

Its a GWT Application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986430/how-we-call-logout-servlet-on-browser-close-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's important to differentiate between a cookie on the client side, and a session on the server side (I think you already knew that).

Usually, for a clean logout, you'll want to call `session.invalidate()` on the servers side, and `Cookies.removeCookie(...)` on the client side.

But not every 'logout' is clean:

- The logout request may not make it to the server
- The browser may crash even before you call removeCookie - so any attempt to remove a cookie on window close will be unreliable

On the server side, you can use timeouts (see the link provided by @thinksteep: [How we call logout servlet on browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986430/how-we-call-logout-servlet-on-browser-close-event)).

For the client side cookie, you can set an expiryDate/maxAge. Or you can use "session cookies": These are the cookies where you don't set expiry or maxAge at all. Most browsers will delete "session cookies" automatically when the browser restarts - but please see [Firefox session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies).

All of this may mean, that cookies are maybe not the best technology for your use case: In general, a cookie is *by design* available in all browser tabs, and the concept of a browser session doesn't even always end, when the browser/window closes (what would it mean on a smartphone anyway?). This is desirable for many current web sites (users don't have to log in explicitly every time), and many users have come to expect this kind of behavior.

For sites that want a "one tab = one session" policy, it's possibly better to store a token e.g. in a Javascript (or GWT) object, and send it with every request. This way, you can log in separately - even as different users - from multiple browser tabs, and once a tab closes, the token is gone. Please note, that a tab may still get restored by the browser on session restore. (I would always combine this technique with a httponly cookie, to avoid [certain kinds of attacks](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html).)