# is it possible to write onbeforeunload like this?

Tags: javascript, browser, onbeforeunload

Is it possible to write onbeforeunload function like this?

```
   window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) { 

            if(return true)
            {
                if(confirm('Are you sure you want to logout'));
                {
                     //logout function
                }
            }
    }
```

If user click on the "leave this page" button I want to ask user to logout the session.
Is it possible?

Comment: what is if return true? just return `Are you sure you want to logout`

Comment: And it should be `confirm` not `confitm`.

Comment: @ArunKillu return message will not work on firefox browser

Answer (score 0):

Is this what You need?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
       if(confirm('Are you sure you want to logout'))
       {
            alert("logout")
       }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You can't do that in onbeforeunload. You need to return a string and alert / confirm is not allowed.

Comment: @putvande try with the code snippet and tell. This is working for me

Comment: @Gowsikan It is working. If i click on browser back button, If I click cancel in confirm box, It should stay on the same page. But It navigates to previous page. There is any option to stay user on the same page

Comment: @CJRamki pl see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986430/how-we-call-logout-servlet-on-browser-close-event

Comment: Thanks guys, I just disable browser back button. I referred this link,(http://programmerslate.blogspot.in/2013/06/disable-back-button-of-your-browser.html?showComment=1384425729990#c5917527548982551705). But I don't know all browsers support this...